# Angular 6 pipe does not render material icon

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, render, angular6

When i would like to show a material icon trough an Angular pipe, it does not work.

Imagine the case, when you have some data and you want to convert it to an icon, example:
You have a list about people who likes ice cream or not, if he likes it, you have the data 'like' and if he does not you have the data 'dislike' and this two parameters you want to convert to an icon 'like' will be '`<mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>`' and 'dislike' will be something else.
I thought it is going to be easy if i use some Pipe but it does not render the icon :(

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uasanh

I assume this is happen because of the chain of rendering elements.

Can anyone provide me some instruction how to make it work?

Comment: this is something I realised today innerHTML does not compile passed HTML for custom angular elements.

Comment: I don't think you call a component in a pipe.
The best I can suggest is for you to use `ngIf`. I mean,  why not?

Comment: @LazaroHenrique  its not about calling a component  in pipe but passing a component in innerHTML.
even this thing won't work [innerHTML]="'<mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>'"

Comment: Thanks the input guys, i wanted to use this with the ngx-datatable but i managed to solve it with some ng-template since innerHTML does not compile.
Again, thanks :)

Comment: can you tell how did you solve this using ng-template?

Comment: Hi @dasfdsa, I hope this helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-daiupg
If you need some explanation in detail please ask :)

Comment: thats great. you can have that as an answer. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 9 - How to add a mat-icon dynamically inside HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63989550/angular-9-how-to-add-a-mat-icon-dynamically-inside-html-page)

Comment: Hi @tinker, unfortunately your suggestion not resolved the issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem i manged to replace the pipes with ng-template.
Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-daiupg

PS: If you want to render icons with ngx-datatable the ng-template can be helpful as well.