# Angular 9 - How to add a mat-icon dynamically inside HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a simple problem with `"@angular/core": "~9.1.6",` and `"@angular/material": "^9.2.3",`, which I need to add random `<mat-icon>done</mat-icon>` elements to an HTML page. I tried to use `DomSanitizer` with pipe but it doesn't work.

Pipe to allow the HTML tag:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'booleanToIcon'
})
export class BooleanToIconPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: string) {
        return this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value));
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

    test:string = '<div><h1><mat-icon>done</mat-icon></h1></div>';

}
```

HTML page:

```
Test:
<span [innerHTML]="test | booleanToIcon"></span>
```

But the generated HTML on WebBrowser doesn't have the `<mat-icon>` element, only contains:

```
<div><h1>done</h1></div>
```

**Note:** without pipe, it also returns the same result

```
Test:
<span [innerHTML]="test"></span>
```

How can I add the full `<mat-icon>done</mat-icon>` HTML element to output HTML page?

Comment: Another way of approaching the issue could be using ComponentFactoryResolver and simply dynamically creating and inserting instances of MatIconComponent. Check [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) for more details.

Comment: @TotallyNewb or much simpler using custom elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By registering the `MatIcon` component as a Custom Element you can easily achieve this:

`ng add @angular/elements`

app.component.ts:

```js
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
  ) {
    const matIconElement = createCustomElement(MatIcon, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('mat-icon', matIconElement);
  }
```

You can then display the custom trusted HTML (using the pipe you described):

```html
<div [innerHTML]="customHtml | trustHtml"></div>
```

NB: Supported web browsers:

[image]